# how to load image data from the bucket to AWS sagemaker notebook?

Tags: python, machine-learning, amazon-s3, deep-learning, amazon-sagemaker

The images are present as folders - train and test in my s3 bucket. I want to use them as it is in my sagemaker notebook. For example, like on my local server I use test_dir = "C:\Users\catvdog\dataset\test".

Answer (score 0):

An example of a dir would be:

```
's3://sagemaker-eu-central-1-123456789/test/sagemaker/sklearncontainer/test'
```

In more general, you create your path for a file

```
data_file = 'filename.csv'
datafolder = 'xxx/yyy'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}/{}'.format(bucket, datafolder, data_file)
```

Comment: train_dir = 's3://sagemaker-us-east-2/catvdog/dataset/train' but getting a file not found error.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Is "sagemaker-us-east-2" really the name of your S3 bucket? That bucket has only the AWS region in the name. My buckets habe a 12 digit number as final part of the bucket name.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is the `s3fs` module.
For example:

```
import s3fs

fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()

directory = 'bucket_name/data'
filenames = fs.ls(directory)
for filename in filenames:
    with fs.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        # do something with file
```

For more information [s3fs documentation](https://fs-s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)